# Rails form submit turboblinks issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created simple a simple form:

```
<%= form_for @passenger do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  </div> 

  <div class="box-footer">
    <%= f.submit 'Cadastrar passageiro', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

After loading the page the submit button won't work. I have to reload the page to make te form submit work.

Now I researched and found out that Turbolinks might be the issue, although there is no JS and nothing involve.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid so that may be the issue:

```
<%= form_for @passenger do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
</div> <!-- what does this close? -->

<div class="box-footer">
  <%= f.submit 'Cadastrar passageiro', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
  <% end %> <!-- your closing the form tag in this div -->
</div>
```

Use:

```
<%= form_for @passenger do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <div class="box-footer">
    <%= f.submit 'Cadastrar passageiro', :class => 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

You can always check our markup via the [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)